# Windows 10: Prevent guest users from deleting files in another drive

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, guest-account

I apologize in advance if this isn't the correct site to ask these type of questions.

I sometimes share my laptop with my small cousin. That being the case I created a guest user in Windows 10 for his use, where many actions require an administrator password. However I noticed that the guest user can still access my secondary drive D: and delete files in that drive without any permission. Is there a way for me to restrict that user's file access to only those in its domain? For example only in that user's default "My Documents" or "Downloads" folder.

To create the guest user, I followed a guide from HowToGeek, and typed the following commands in command prompt from administrator:

C:\WINDOWS\system32> net user Visitor /add /active:yes

C:\WINDOWS\system32> net user Visitor *

C:\WINDOWS\system32> net localgroup users Visitor /delete

C:\WINDOWS\system32> net localgroup guests Visitor /add

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to create a new user account for him in Windows 10 under Settings/ Accounts/Family and Other People/Add a Family Member.  Follow the prompts and save the new profile.  If you don't want to use this method, there are a few other ways of creating it.

[Create and Manage User Accounts in Windows 10](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=26)

Once you have created the new account, you can edit the security properties of any folder or drive for this or any other existing account.  Open Windows Explorer, navigate to the drive you want (in this example, I'll use C:) and right-click on it.  Then click Properties.

[image]

Once you have accessed the Properties menu, click on Security.

[image]

Then click on Edit and select the group/user whose access you would like to restrict.

[image]

Choose Deny for all options, unless you want something more specific than just denying access across the board.  For example, you can allow for Read or Read and Execute if there are any .exe files you want to let him run, but you'll definitely want to avoid checking Full Control or Modify, depending on what you are trying to prevent.  Of course, you can get even more specific under Advanced.

[image]

After you have checked the appropriate boxes, click Apply.

Using this method, you can customize the permissions of any folder or drive for each specific user on your system.